# Hide infoWindow when clicked marker second time (Google Map Android API V2)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

To achieve this I feel I simply need to override `onMarkerClick` and check if the infoWindow of clicked marker has already been open, but to my surprise `clickedMarker.isInfoWindowShown()` always return false...

My codes:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker clickedMarker) {
    if(clickedMarker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
        clickedMarker.hideInfoWindow();
        System.out.println("was showing");
    } else {
        clickedMarker.showInfoWindow();
        System.out.println("not showing");
    }
}
```

It always tells me the infoWindow is "not showing" which is not right... I can get around this by keeping a reference of `userLastClickedMarker` but I'd like to know where I did wrong above.

Thanks!

Edit:

I changed my code to debug this issue:

```
    System.out.println(clickedMarker.isInfoWindowShown());
    if(clickedMarker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
        clickedMarker.hideInfoWindow();
        System.out.println(" showing");
    } else {
        clickedMarker.showInfoWindow();
        System.out.println("not showing");
    }
    System.out.println(clickedMarker.isInfoWindowShown());
```

I found that `isInfoWindowShown()` does work correctly in onMarkerClick method but won't 'remember' it correctly. And I found this has been pointed out as a bug by someone already...

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5408

Comment: You may try calling your code with a small delay using `Handler`. I also suggest putting a link to this question as a comment to issue 5048.

Comment: Did you find any work around? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: remember to star the bug at the link please, if you reach this post.

Comment: I see the same issue, any work around anyone?

Comment: Yes, this problem. But where I calling isInfoWindowShown() into infowindowadapter, all ok. What to to?

Comment: You can use setOnInfoWindowClickListener if the purpose is to remove info window on subsequent click . but the click has to be on the info window. Hope it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

isInfoWindowShown always false, so I hide info window using the basic way

```
int mLastIndex = -1
```

and on

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {   
    int index = (int) marker.getTag();
    Log.i(TAG, "onMarkerClick: " + index);
    if(lastIndex != index){
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        lastIndex = index;
    }else{
        marker.hideInfoWindow();
        lastIndex = -1;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I found a simple solution by declaring a global boolean variable and switching its value when user clicks on a marker. Here's my code:

```
private boolean isInfoWindowShown = false;

   map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

            if (!isInfoWindowShown) {

                marker.showInfoWindow();
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()));
                isInfoWindowShown = true;
            } else {

                marker.hideInfoWindow();
                isInfoWindowShown = false;
            }

           return true;
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it is correct:

> An info window allows you to display information to the user when they
>   tap on a marker. Only one info window is displayed at a time. If a
>   user clicks on another marker, the current info window will be hidden
>   and the new info window will be displayed.

We may consider that as bug from usage perspective.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
```

From business logic this is not the proper place to call `marker.isInfoWindowShown()` function because it's always false as supposed to be. When OnMarkerClickListener call this function any opened `InfoWindow` have been already hidden by Map framework itself (so status 'false' technically is correct).

You can check that by example modifying overridden `onMarkerClick` method
to open `InfoWindows` on even cliks only. On odd cliks - do nothing and see `InfoWindows` closes automatically by framework without explicit call to `marker.hideInfoWindow()`;

To get actual `InfoWindow` status you should call `marker.isInfoWindowShown` from another events or functions by keeping local references to any markers on map.

Comment: When this method onMarkerClick is called the marker.isInfoWindowShown is called on a particular marker and so accordingly the status of infoWindow should be given for that very marker. So how the status 'false' is technically correct i am not able to understand. Even though handling onInfoWindowClick solves this problem yet this remains unresolved why isInfoWindowShown always returns false.

Comment: Because map framework already closed InfoWindow before it calls  onMarkerClick method.

Comment: is it why isInfoWindowShown always returns false

Comment: Yes, determining `isInfoWindowShown` from inside of methode `onMarkerClick` always returns false.

Comment: thanks for updating as it is not even mentioned in the API method reference or anywhere else.

Comment: so there is no way to determine if infoWindowIsShown when the marker is clicked?!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am showing my own window info upon google window info,

[My window info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfsQz.png)

And I was need to hide google window info any time user clicks on other place e.g map,buttons .

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    Marker lastMarkerClicked = modelManager.getLastMarkerClicked();
    if(lastMarkerClicked!=null){
        lastMarkerClicked.hideInfoWindow();
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

But I also need googles window info because one of my features is to share screenshot of map , and there window info is needed for the screenshot feature.

( For this to work The popup window should lose focus So its focusable property should be set to true )

Answer (score -1):

I create this code for show/hide infowindow.

```
enter code here

private boolean infoWindowIsShow = false;
private Marker lastMarker;

private class MarkerClickListener implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        //обработка выводить/не выводить инфовиндов
        if(lastMarker == null){
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            lastMarker = marker;
            infoWindowIsShow=true;
        }else
        if (marker.getId().equals(lastMarker.getId())) {
            if (infoWindowIsShow) {
                marker.hideInfoWindow();
                infoWindowIsShow = false;
            } else {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                infoWindowIsShow = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            //это щелчок по другому маркеру
            if (infoWindowIsShow) {//если открыто инфовиндов предыдущего маркера, скрываем его
                lastMarker.hideInfoWindow();
                //и отображаем для нового
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                infoWindowIsShow = true;
                lastMarker = marker;
            } else {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                infoWindowIsShow = true;
                lastMarker = marker;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new MarkerClickListener());